# Javascript 'x is not a function'

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to start and stop two videos with two separate buttons. I've simply copied the code and renamed the variables, yet one piece of code works and one doesn't. I get the error 'TypeError: video2.pause is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.c'. Both videos and buttons are placed in modals respectively. Why am I getting this weird error, especially when exactly the same code works?

Javascript:

```
    var video = document.getElementById("video.mp4");
    var playButton = document.getElementById("play-pause");

    var video2 = document.getElementById("video2.mp4");
    var play = document.getElementById("play-pause2");

    playButton.addEventListener("click", function a () {
        if (video.paused == true) {
          video.play();
          playButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
        } else {
          video.pause();
          playButton.innerHTML = "Play";
        }
      });

    play.addEventListener("click", function c () { 
        if (video2.paused == true) { 
          video2.play(); 
          play.innerHTML = "Pause"; 
        } else {
          video2.pause();
          play.innerHTML = "Play"; 
        }
      });
```

HTML:

```
    <video width="900px" height="600px" id="Digital_Poster.mp4" />
      <source src="assets/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" id="video.mp4"/>
         Sorry, this browser does not support the 'video' tag.
    </video>
    <div id="video-controls">
      <button type="button" id="play-pause">Play</button>
    </div>

    <video width="900px" height="600px">
      <source src="assets/video2.mp4" type="video/mp4" id="video2.mp4"/>
         Sorry, this browser does not support the 'video' tag.
    </video>
    <div id="video-controls">
      <button type="button" id="play-pause2">Play</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where are you video elements? I don't see them in your code...

Comment: Well you don't show any element with the ID `"video2.mp4"`, so there's that...

Comment: Also in JavaScript your two buttons have IDs `play-pause` and `play-pause2`, while in your HTML they are called `play` and `play-pause`...

Comment: @squint Sorry, I cut it out as I didn't think it would be relevant and the community guidelines allow for basic HTML

Comment: @Frxstrem That's been updated to how it appears in the code, apologies

Comment: Is `.` a valid character in IDs? I don't think so. Because then `#video.mp4` will be interpretted as an element with the ID `video` and the class `mp4`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Periods [are completely valid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html#79022) in IDs. Not recommended, because you'll have to escape it in CSS (`#video\.mp4`) otherwise it'll be interpreted as you said.

Comment: @jmendeth I didn't know that. So thanks.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir you're welcome :) I admit I had to look it up to make sure as well

Answer (score 1):

You should call `.pause` on the `<video>` elements, but the `id` is set on  the `<source>` ones. Moving it to the `<video>` tags should make it work:

```
    <video width="900px" height="600px" id="video.mp4">
      <source src="assets/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
         Sorry, this browser does not support the 'video' tag.
    </video>
    <div id="video-controls">
      <button type="button" id="play-pause">Play</button>
    </div>

    <video width="900px" height="600px" id="video2.mp4">
      <source src="assets/video2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
         Sorry, this browser does not support the 'video' tag.
    </video>
    <div id="video-controls">
      <button type="button" id="play-pause2">Play</button>
    </div>
```

By the way, I've corrected the `/>` to `>` in the first line. Also, declaring two elements with ID set to `video-controls` is illegal, consider using [HTML classes](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp) (thanks @zer00ne for pointing out).

Comment: Ids are unique you should pay attention to your own work before you critique others.

Comment: What do you mean? The two IDs are different, this code works [(jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/1cvxyeuv)

Comment: @zer00ne Oh! I understand, you were talking about the `video-controls` id which is repeated... It wasn't the cause of the problem but I've added a note for the OP to fix it too. Thanks!